# Object is not moving proper with mouse movement in mobile devices

Tags: createjs, easeljs, animate-cc

I am trying to move an object with mouse using pressmove event on the object. In PC and Tablet it is working well. But, in the mobile devices it is not working well as those have different width and height.

You can view the following URL:-
http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http://saurabhysecit.byethost15.com/scratchGame_Canvas.html&w=320&h=568&a=37&s=1

Direct URL is - http://saurabhysecit.byethost15.com/scratchGame_Canvas.html

It has been generated from Animate CC.
These are the code below.

JS Code -

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
lib.ssMetadata = [];

function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }


(lib.coin = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#AA8801").ss(1,2,1).p("AH5AAQAACrhhCBQgIAKgIAKQgQAUgTASQiKCLjAAKQgNAAgOAAQi5AAiKh2QgRgOgQgRQiUiTAAjTQAAjDCBiOIAAgBQAJgKAKgKQAUgUAVgSQB9hlCigIQAOgBAOAAQAaAAAZACQAHAAAHABQCoAUB8B9QATASAQAUQBtCEAECvQAAADAAACQAAAFAAADg");
    this.shape.setTransform(-4.8,0.1);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#D9AE01").s().p("AlbGiQgTgQgSgSQigieAAjiQAAjhCgifQAWgWAXgTQCRh2DCgBQAdABAbACQC+ARCLCMQAUATASAWQB6CTAADEQAADGh6CSQgSAVgUATQiUCWjQAKIgdAAQjHAAiUh+gAgqnnQijAIh8BmQgVARgUAUIgUAUIAAABQiBCOAADEQAADSCVCTQAQARARAOQCJB2C6AAIAbAAQDAgJCJiMQATgSAQgUIAQgUQBhiBAAiqIAAgJIAAgGQgEithtiFQgQgTgTgTQh7h9ipgTIAAgDQgYgCgaAAQgVAAgVACg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(-3.3,-1.7);

    this.shape_2 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_2.graphics.f("#FFCC00").s().p("AlDGFQgQgOgQgQQiViUAAjSQAAjDCBiPIAAAAIAUgVQAUgUAUgRQB9hmCigIQAWgCAVAAQAZAAAZACIAAADIgNgCQgZgCgbAAIgcABIAcgBQAbAAAZACIANACQCoATB8B9QATATAQAUQBsCEAFCvIAAAFIAAAIQAACqhhCCIgQATQgQAUgTATQiKCLjAAJIgbABQi5AAiKh3g");
    this.shape_2.setTransform(-4.8,0.1);

    this.shape_3 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_3.graphics.f("#695400").s().p("Ah6I1IgBAAQjHgKiUiJQCUB+DIAAIAeAAQDOgKCUiWQAUgTASgWQB6iSAAjFQAAjEh6iTQgSgWgUgUQiKiLi+gRQgbgDgdAAQjCAAiSB3QCSiBDBgKIABAAIAfAAIAbAAIAAAAQDXAJCbCcIAaAbIACAEQCJCcAADUIAAACQgBDViICaIgCAEQgMANgOANQikCmjpAAIgfAAg");
    this.shape_3.setTransform(9,-1.7);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_3},{t:this.shape_2},{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(1));

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.coin, new cjs.Rectangle(-57.8,-58.2,113.9,113.1), null);


// stage content:
(lib.scratchGame_Canvas = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
if (loop == null) { loop = false; } this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        var pressBool=false;
        var mask_mc = new createjs.Shape();
        var bg_mc = new createjs.Bitmap("images/YLogo1.jpg");
        //var coin_mc = new lib.coin();
        var coin_mc = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("#FFFFFF").drawCircle(0, 0, 50));

        coin_mc.x = stage.canvas.width/2;
        coin_mc.y = stage.canvas.width/2;

        stage.addChild(bg_mc, coin_mc);
        createjs.Touch.enable(stage, false, true);

        if(sRatio<1){
            coin_mc.scaleX = coin_mc.scaleY = sRatio;
        }
        coin_mc.addEventListener('pressmove', moveCoin.bind(this));
        coin_mc.addEventListener('mouseup', releaseCoin.bind(this));
        updateCacheImage(false);

        function moveCoin(e){       
            e.currentTarget.x = e.stageX;
            e.currentTarget.y = e.stageY;
            stage.update();
            createMask(e);
        }

        function createMask(e) {
            if(!pressBool)return;
            var xLoc = stage.mouseX-20;
            var yLoc = stage.mouseY-30;
            mask_mc.graphics.beginFill("FFFFFF").drawEllipse(xLoc, yLoc, 40, 60);
            updateCacheImage(true);
        }
        function updateCacheImage(update){
            var w = 361;
            if (update) {
                mask_mc.updateCache();
            } else {
                mask_mc.cache(0, 0, w, w);
            }

            maskFilter = new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(mask_mc.cacheCanvas);

            bg_mc.filters = [maskFilter];
            if (update) {
                bg_mc.updateCache(0, 0, w, w);
            } else {
                bg_mc.cache(0, 0, w, w);
            }
        }
        function releaseCoin(e) {
            //stage.canvas.style.cursor = "default";
            pressBool = false;
            updateCacheImage(true);
        }
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(1));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(385.9,359.4,113.9,113);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 550,
    height: 400,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#999999",
    opacity: 1.00,
    manifest: [],
    preloads: []
};
})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss, AdobeAn;

HTML Code:- 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    NOTES:
    1. All tokens are represented by '$' sign in the template.
    2. You can write your code only wherever mentioned.
    3. All occurrences of existing tokens will be replaced by their appropriate values.
    4. Blank lines will be removed automatically.
    5. Remove unnecessary comments before creating your template.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
<title>scratchGame_Canvas</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="scratchGame_Canvas.js?1497868121984"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio, yRatio, sRatio=1;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    handleComplete();
}
function handleComplete() {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    exportRoot = new lib.scratchGame_Canvas();
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot); 
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }       
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    function makeResponsive(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {      
        var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
        resizeCanvas();     
        function resizeCanvas() {
            var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;
            var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;
            pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;
            if(isResp) {                
                if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
                    sRatio = lastS;                
                }               
                else if(!isScale) {                 
                    if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                        sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }
                else if(scaleType==1) {
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
                }
                else if(scaleType==2) {
                    sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }
            }
            canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;         
            canvas.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
            canvas.style.width = dom_overlay_container.style.width = anim_container.style.width =  w*sRatio+'px';               
            canvas.style.height = anim_container.style.height = dom_overlay_container.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
            stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;
            stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;
            lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;     
        }
    }
    makeResponsive(true,'both',false,1);
    fnStartAnimation();
}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(153, 153, 153, 1.00); width:550px; height:400px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(153, 153, 153, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:550px; height:400px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Hope to get response soon.

Thanks.
```

Comment: 1) It would be better if you post your code (and not just post the URL to it). 2) Looking at the code in your Animate CC proyect, I'm looking that your canvas is responsive both by width and height (`makeResponsive(true,'both',false,1);`). Have your tried a transformation of the coordinates used in the function `moveCoin()`?

Comment: yeah i had tried but get almost same issue.

Comment: I asked that, because the responsivity you have in your canvas, makes it scalable, so the x/y mouse position are subject to that scale. An alternative (I am pretty sure there are more ones) is to transform your coordinates using the  `globalToLocal() ` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can transform the coordinates, so your x/y mouse position is not affected by the canvas scaling by responsiveness, and one alternative is to use, in the binded function with the `pressmove` event (in your case, the function `moveCoin()`), the `globalToLocal()` method.

## scratchGame_Canvas.js

### Function moveCoin()

```
function moveCoin(e){   
    var point;

    point = stage.globalToLocal(e.stageX, e.stageY); 
    e.currentTarget.x = point.x;
    e.currentTarget.y = point.y;
    stage.update();
    createMask(e);
}
```

**See also**: [Drag and drop with easeljs in Animate CC 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413936/drag-and-drop-with-easeljs-in-animate-cc-2017)
 & [MovieClip class (EaselJS API)](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MovieClip.html)